# How to populate a TableView column with data from two different database columns

Tags: javafx, tableview

I'd like to populate a TableView column with data from two different database table columns, one with users' first names another with the second and another the last.

The only way I know how can only do so from one database column onto one TableView column at a time:

```
name.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<RevEntity, String>("firstName"));
```

from a pojo like:

```
public class UserEntity extends RevEntity {

    private String firstName;
    private String secondName;
    private String otherNames;
```

What I'd like is something similar to String concat.

I know this doesn't work. Just shows the idea I have:

```
name.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<RevEntity, String>("firstName" + "secondName" + "otherNames"));
```

Please help on how to go about this. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a `Callback` in the `setCellValueFactory()`, override its `call()` and return a `ObservableValue<String>` from the method. This ObservableValue will be the concatenation of your `FirstName` and `SecondName` and so on..

I am just considering it as *firstName* and *lastName*

```
name.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Person, String>,
                                                           ObservableValue<String>>() {
        @Override
        public ObservableValue<String> call(
                TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Person, String> p) {
            return new SimpleStringProperty(p.getValue().getFirstName()
                    + " " + p.getValue().getLastName());
        }
});
```